# Why are INNER JOIN queries so slow? - LEFT JOINS speed things up

Tags: mysql

Good morning.

Can somebody explain to me, why in MySQL, if I will make couple `INNER JOINS` and add simple condition in `WHERE` clouse on indexed column from one of joined tables, joins are performed first, and the intermediate result is scanned for provided condition?

I would think, that optimized query should first pick up proper rows from table included in where clause, and than perform proper joins, as this would reduce table reads am I wrong? Current behaviour seams just stupid to me. Example of such behaviour is below.

```
explain select 
    patent0_.id as id1_6_0_,
    referencen1_.id as id1_7_1_,
    service2_.id as id1_8_2_,
    applicant3_.id as id1_0_3_,
    country4_.id as id1_2_4_,
    patent0_.applicant_id as applica14_6_0_,
    patent0_.applicationDate as applicat2_6_0_,
    patent0_.applicationLanguage as applicat3_6_0_,
    patent0_.applicationNumber as applicat4_6_0_,
    patent0_.classification as classifi5_6_0_,
    patent0_.creationDate as creation6_6_0_,
    patent0_.disabled as disabled7_6_0_,
    patent0_.licenceInfo as licenceI8_6_0_,
    patent0_.patentName as patentNa9_6_0_,
    patent0_.publicationDate as publica10_6_0_,
    patent0_.publicationNumber as publica11_6_0_,
    patent0_.registrationDate as registr12_6_0_,
    patent0_.registrationNumber as registr13_6_0_,
    referencen1_.creationDate as creation2_7_1_,
    referencen1_.design_id as design_i8_7_1_,
    referencen1_.error as error3_7_1_,
    referencen1_.hasRenewal as hasRenew4_7_1_,
    referencen1_.info as info5_7_1_,
    referencen1_.patent_id as patent_i9_7_1_,
    referencen1_.referenceNumber as referenc6_7_1_,
    referencen1_.service_id as service10_7_1_,
    referencen1_.trademark_id as tradema11_7_1_,
    referencen1_.type as type7_7_1_,
    service2_.additional_name as addition2_8_2_,
    service2_.name as name3_8_2_,
    applicant3_.address as address2_0_3_,
    applicant3_.addressSource_id as address13_0_3_,
    applicant3_.city as city3_0_3_,
    applicant3_.country_id as country14_0_3_,
    applicant3_.createdDate as createdD4_0_3_,
    applicant3_.deleted as deleted5_0_3_,
    applicant3_.disabled as disabled6_0_3_,
    applicant3_.entryCount as entryCou7_0_3_,
    applicant3_.entryCountChanged as entryCou8_0_3_,
    applicant3_.manualModified as manualMo9_0_3_,
    applicant3_.modifiedDate as modifie10_0_3_,
    applicant3_.name as name11_0_3_,
    applicant3_.zipCode as zipCode12_0_3_,
    country4_.dateFormat as dateForm2_2_4_,
    country4_.englishName as englishN3_2_4_,
    country4_.iso3166 as iso4_2_4_,
    country4_.locale as locale5_2_4_,
    country4_.name as name6_2_4_,
    country4_.polishName as polishNa7_2_4_
from 
    patent patent0_
        inner join 
    referencenumber referencen1_ ON patent0_.id = referencen1_.patent_id
        inner join
    service service2_ ON referencen1_.service_id = service2_.id
        inner join
    applicant applicant3_ ON patent0_.applicant_id = applicant3_.id
        inner join
    country country4_ ON applicant3_.country_id = country4_.id
where
    patent0_.applicant_id = 102014
```

Result of explain:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                                                         | key                          | key_len | ref                               | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | applicant3_  | const  | PRIMARY,FK_cjteymxk1h6sce00e4vtar8we                                  | PRIMARY                      | 4       | const                             |     1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | country4_    | const  | PRIMARY                                                               | PRIMARY                      | 4       | const                             |     1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | service2_    | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                               | NULL                         | NULL    | NULL                              |    27 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | referencen1_ | ref    | patent_id_UNIQUE,FK_fcy9m21m0jaid4l8e8bbsms1v,FK_5lMjxN8AZfRUOuCWebvP | FK_fcy9m21m0jaid4l8e8bbsms1v | 5       | trademarks.service2_.id           | 60454 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | patent0_     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK_8991d6757d10418eaa7cd8fe1da                                | PRIMARY                      | 4       | trademarks.referencen1_.patent_id |     1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

I was expecting that this query will first fetch all patents with proper applicant_id and than perform `INNER JOINS` on that rows. In order to achieve that I have to change all inner joint into left joins. 
So why the `INNER JOINS` have such terrible optimization path? How to fix that? 
As requested, here is execution plan for the same query with `LEFT JOINS` insteed of `INNER JOINS`

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+---------+-------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                            | key                            | key_len | ref                                | rows    | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+---------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | patent0_     | ref    | FK_8991d6757d10418eaa7cd8fe1da           | FK_8991d6757d10418eaa7cd8fe1da | 5       | const                              |      86 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | referencen1_ | ref    | patent_id_UNIQUE,FK_5lMjxN8AZfRUOuCWebvP | patent_id_UNIQUE               | 5       | trademarks.patent0_.id             | 1632272 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | service2_    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                  | PRIMARY                        | 4       | trademarks.referencen1_.service_id |       1 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | applicant3_  | const  | PRIMARY                                  | PRIMARY                        | 4       | const                              |       1 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | country4_    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                  | PRIMARY                        | 4       | trademarks.applicant3_.country_id  |       1 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Any particular problems with the given plan?

Comment: @Karunakar: it's completely irrelevant, please delete it.

Comment: @zerkms, Yes, the query execution is very long (like 5 sec). After switcing inner joins into left joins, query execution is around 0,050ms. The point is, why the lookup is not performed on table from where clouse first, and join later?

Comment: @Antoniossss any chance to see execution plan for a query with left joins? PS: without `\G` please though )) It's much easier to read here

Comment: You have cache left after performing inner join. Empty the cache, run it again with left join as first option, then post the result of explain like @zerkms suggested (without \G).

Comment: Both execution plans are after flushing cache

Comment: A plan for `LEFT JOIN`s looks worse. So when you run `INNER JOIN` right after `LEFT JOIN` it's still slow?

Comment: Yes it is, but I think that this is irrelevant. 
Could you please explain why is it worst? Only 86 joins are performed, insteed of over 60 000

Comment: `1632272 * 86 > 60454 * 27`

Comment: But this are only possible lookups count, 68 rows get joined. While with inner join, joins are performed first and where filtering is in the last step, am I correct? Relation between patent - referencenumber is 1:1.

Comment: And still, left joins are ultra fast, while inner joins take ~6;7 seconds